# Difference between Ocean-Ocean subduction and Continental-Ocean from earthquake data

Tags: plate-tectonics

I am having a hard time finding this anywhere -- if no one can answer, I would appreciate a reference.
I was doing introductory homework in earth science, and we had to determine the kind of plate boundary via earthquake data.

We were given earthquake depths and locations at certain distances away from an oceanic trench. There were several volcanoes given as well (at depth of zero, a certain distance away from the trench).

Given the diversity of the depths of these earthquakes (ranging from 100km - 600km), it was easy to tell that it was a convergent boundary. The trench gives away that at least one plate is oceanic.

But I can't figure out how to tell from this data whether or not the collision is Ocean-Continent, or Ocean to Ocean.

Is there a way to tell just from the data given?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how you can answer this... You can plot the earthquakes data to get an image of the [Wadati–Benioff zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadati%E2%80%93Benioff_zone), but all it can tell you is the angle of dip of the slab, which is linked to its age (older oceanic lithosphere is denser hence sink faster).